# MaterialButton wider than it should be

Tags: android, xml, android-button, material-components-android

After implementing a `MaterialButton`, its width doesn't seem to wrap to the text inside for some reason leaving extra space to the right. Does the `MaterialButton` need to be inside a `ConstraintLayout` for this to work? Or is there something in my code that is incorrect?

**button layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MaterialButton` uses a style that, deep in its hierarchy, inherits from `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button`, which defines this attribute:

```
<item name="android:minWidth">88dip</item>
```

You can override this in your own style/theme or directly on your `<Button>` tag:

```
android:minWidth="1dp"
```

You can see this by viewing the quick documentation for the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` style (scroll to the bottom):

[image]